# Not able to load angular 2 in IE

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, angular

Working in a angular4 application and can't able to load the application in IE. I am using the following versions.

```
Node -v7.2.1
npm -v3.10.10
typescript- v2.2.1
Webpack -v2.2.1 and using ES6 module in tsconfig.json
@angular/core 4.0.0
```

How to load angular2 app in IE.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your index.html (top of the head tag):

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js" type="text/plain"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.js" type="text/plain"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=edge;IE=10" />
```

Comment: I have updated the npm packages to latest version @angular/xxxx v4.0.0 and using ECMA Script 6.How can we load the application in IE11